# Using List-command with variable names as values

Tags: stata

I want to use the list command in the following way:

`list var1 var2 var3  if condition`

`var1` and `var2` are normal variables and I want their values displayed with the list command. `var3` however should be a variable which has the variable name of `var2`.

The result would be:

`value_of_var1 | value_of_var2 | variable_name_var2`

I know that works in SPSS but have no idea how to do that in Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why you want this (but I am sure you have a good reason) so I am not sure this is the best solution, but you could do this:

```
gen var3 = "variable_name_var2"

list var1 var2 var3 if condition
```

It might be a bit manual but since you did not state that you will repeat this for many variables, it might work for you.